# Replace child in XML

Tags: php, html, xml

```
<?php
$files = glob('users/*.xml');
foreach($files as $file) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file, 0, true);
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)" value="'. basename($file) .'"></td>
            <td class="alternate-row1">'. basename($file, '.xml') .'</td>
            <td><span id="itm1" onclick="exchange(this.id)">'. $xml->name .'</span><input id="itm1b" class="replace" type="text" name="newname"></td>
            <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->lastname .'</td>
            <td>'. $xml->email .'</td>
            <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->level .'</td>
            <td>'. $xml->birthday .'</td>
            <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->gender .'</td>
            <td>'. $xml->age .'</td>
            <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->country .'</td>
        </tr>';
}
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
    $member = $_POST['newname'];
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('users/' . basename($file) . '.xml');
    $editname = $dom->getElementsByTagName('name');
    $newname = $dom->createTextNode($member);
    foreach ($editname as $edit) {
       $edit->parentNode->replaceChild($newname, $edit);
    }
    $dom->save('users/' . basename($file) . '.xml');
}
?>
```

So I've made this code, as you can see it got DOM and Simple XML element.
I trying to replace child using `$_POST` throw input command, the input box is in the echo part above and I using js replacement code, it replace text to input text by onclick command (not really important for my question, it just for explaining).
Anyway I got little stuck with the code since it not working, I got set the `$_POST`, I try use some guides I found in Stack Overflow but it didn't work since it not matches my code.

Do you have any answer to me?

Thank you for the assistance, Y. D.

Comment: I'm not so sure but, your solution seems overkill to me. Why not calling a php through ajax and according to result, updating dom from javascript?

Comment: No... it impossible acctualy to update dom from js, only from PHP, my problem that something is missing or i using DOM instead SimpleXML but i not sure how to fix it or what my real problem after all that why i asked this question.

Comment: please show your xml and a sample of your desired xml.

Comment: I dont think the xml have a part of it, it normal XML version 1.0  the name element is the one i wish to edit.

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Example using `simplexml` ---> see live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2oR5Wk

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<root>
    <head>
        <name id="1">test</name>
        <name id="2">file</name>
        <name id="3">name</name>
    </head>
</root>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($xml);
echo "</pre>";

$x = count($xml->head->name)-1;

for ($x; $x>=0; $x--) {

    $xml->head->name[$x] = "newname";

} 

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```